# Estimating Key Threshold from a Series of Significance Values

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, p-value

I'm measuring the effect of a continuous treatment. At each observed treatment level I'm able to estimate the significance for the effect. I'd like to identify a critical value of the treatment, e.g. at treatment levels greater than *x* I have > 95% confidence that the treatment is significant. Can anyone suggest a procedure to estimate *x*?

[image: Scatter plot of p-value vs. Treatment]

Visually, it seems clear that when the treatment level exceeds 0.35, then the effect is significant, but I'd like to be able to say that with at least some statistical rigor.

Comment: What does it mean to you that you have $95\%$ confidence that a treatment is "significant"?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to identify a critical value of the treatment, above which I can be confident in a prediction as to whether the treatment will have an effect. E.g. at a treatment level of 0.1, I have no confidence that I can predict its effect, but at a level of 0.75 I have high confidence that I can predict the treatment's effect.

Comment: More generically, looking at the plot above, there's clearly something different about treatment levels greater than about 0.35. I'd like to be more precise than "about" and more rigorous with 0.35.